# import requests ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, modulenotfounderror

I ran the code import requests in my file and this error come out ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Things I have tried:

installed requests in both windows terminal and vscode terminal that gives the output Requirement already satisfied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right python interpreter selected in the lower right hand corner of the VSCode window. If it's not right, you can change it by clicking on the interpreter version:

[image: VSCode bottom tab]

[image: Changing the interpreter in VSCode]